# Email is not being sent. Please tell the problem?

Tags: python, email, automation, smtp, smtplib

Please tell the error in the code. Output is always "Email not sent"

```
import smtplib

port = 587
sender_mail = input("Enter your email address :  ")
sender_password = input("Enter your password :  ")
receiver_mail = input("Enter receiver's mail address :  ")
message = input("Enter the message you want to send ")

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",port)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(sender_mail,sender_password)
    server.sendmail(sender_mail,receiver_mail,message)
    print("Email sent successfully")
    server.quit()
except:
    print("Email not sent")
    server.quit()
```

Comment: change the except to `except Exception as e:` and then print e to see the error message

Answer (score 1):

Change your `except:` , to get exception text

```
 try:
    #Your code
 except Exception as e:
    print("Email not sent, Exception:", str(e))
    server.quit()
```